# Javascript: set label text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a generic function for a form with several fields in the following format.

```
<label id="LblTextCount"></label>
<textarea name="text" onKeyPress="checkLength(this, 512, LblTextCount)">
</textarea>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
function checkLength(object, maxlength, label) {
    charsleft = (maxlength - object.value.length);

    // never allow to exceed the specified limit
    if( charsleft < 0 ) {
        object.value = object.value.substring(0, maxlength-1);
    }

    // I'm trying to set the value of charsleft into the label
label.innerText = charsleft;
    document.getElementById('LblTextCount').InnerHTML = charsleft;
}
```

The first part works fine, but I'm **not able to set the `charsleft`value into the label**. What am I doing wrong?
Please note that I'm looking for a dynamic approach instead of hard coding the label name into the JS function. JQuery would be fine too :)

---

**Solution** - thanks to all!

HTML

```
<label id="LblTextCount"></label>
<textarea name="text">
</textarea>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea[name=text]').keypress(function(e) {
        checkLength($(this),512,$('#LblTextCount'));
    }).focus(function() {
        checkLength($(this),512,$('#LblTextCount'));
    });
});

function checkLength(obj, maxlength, label) {
    var charsleft = (maxlength - obj.val().length);

    // never allow to exceed the specified limit
    if( charsleft < 0 ) {
        obj.val(obj.val().substring(0, maxlength-1));
    }

    // set the value of charsleft into the label
    $(label).html(charsleft);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

InnerHTML should be innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('LblAboutMeCount').innerHTML = charsleft;
```

You should bind your `checkLength` function to your textarea with jQuery rather than calling it inline and rather intrusively:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('textarea[name=text]').keypress(function(e) {
        checkLength($(this),512,$('#LblTextCount'));
    }).focus(function() {
        checkLength($(this),512,$('#LblTextCount'));
    });
});
```

You can neaten up checkLength by using more jQuery, and I wouldn't use 'object' as a formal parameter:

```
function checkLength(obj, maxlength, label) {
    charsleft = (maxlength - obj.val().length);
    // never allow to exceed the specified limit
    if( charsleft < 0 ) {
        obj.val(obj.val().substring(0, maxlength-1));
    }
    // I'm trying to set the value of charsleft into the label
    label.text(charsleft);
    $('#LblAboutMeCount').html(charsleft);
}
```

So if you apply the above, you can change your markup to:

```
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: Is there an elegant way to also bind checkLength() to onFocus respective onPaste without duplicating the content of the $(document).ready(function()) function?

Comment: @MrG - It is, see my edit. Also not that the paste event is not cross-browser.

Comment: Tkx karim79, it works perfectly fine in a separate window (all browser listed below) but fails within a JQuery UI tab without any errors in the console (FF/Safari/Opera fails, IE works fine). Do you have an idea? Many, many thanks!

Comment: @MrG - I bet those are ajax tabs. Try replacing $('textarea[name=text]').keypress(function(e) { with $('textarea[name=text]').live("keypress",function(e) {...

Answer (score 3):

you are doing several things wrong. The explanation follows the corrected code:

```
<label id="LblTextCount"></label>
<textarea name="text" onKeyPress="checkLength(this, 512, 'LblTextCount')">
</textarea>
```

Note the quotes around the id.

```
function checkLength(object, maxlength, label) {
    charsleft = (maxlength - object.value.length);

    // never allow to exceed the specified limit
    if( charsleft < 0 ) {
        object.value = object.value.substring(0, maxlength-1);
    }

    // set the value of charsleft into the label
    document.getElementById(label).innerHTML = charsleft;
}
```

First, on your key press event you need to send the label id as a string for it to read correctly. Second, InnerHTML has a lowercase i. Lastly, because you sent the function the string id you can get the element by that id.

Let me know how that works out for you

**EDIT** Not that by not declaring charsleft as a var, you are implicitly creating a global variable. a better way would be to do the following when declaring it in the function:

```
var charsleft = ....
```

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamic approach, if your labels are always in front of your text areas:

```
$(object).prev("label").text(charsleft);
```